# Show duplicate rows(all columns of that row) where all columns are duplicate except one column

Tags: sql, teradata

In below table, I need to select duplicate records where all columns are duplicate except Customer Type and Price for a particular week.

For e.g

```
Week Customer  Product  Customer Type   Price
1    Alex      Cycle    Consumer        100
1    Alex      Cycle    Reseller        101
2    John      Motor    Consumer        200
3    John      Motor    Consumer        200
3    John      Motor    Reseller        201
```

I am using below query but this query doesn't show me both costumer type, it just shows me consumer count(*) for a combination.

```
select Week, Customer, product, count(distinct Customer Type)
from table
group by Week, Customer, product
having count(distinct Customer Type) > 1
```

I would like to see below result, that shows me duplicate values and not just the count(*) of duplicate row. I am trying to see customers assigned to multiple customer types in a particular week for a product and at the same time show me all columns. It doesn't matter if the price is different.

```
Week Customer  Product  Customer Type   Price
1    Alex      Cycle    Consumer        100
1    Alex      Cycle    Reseller        101
3    John      Motor    Consumer        200
3    John      Motor    Reseller        201
```

Thanks

Shaki

Comment: which RDBMS you are using please tag it.

Comment: please add a tag that tells us which database you use. "SQL" isn't sufficient to tell use what options and syntax to propose.

Comment: looks like you need row_number if your DB supports it

Answer (score 2):

```
 WITH CustomerDistribution_CTE (WeekC ,CustomerC,  ProductC)
    AS
    (
    select Week, Customer, product
    from Your_Table_Name group by Week, Customer, 
    product having count(distinct CustomerType) > 1
    )
    SELECT Y.*
    FROM CustomerDistribution_CTE C
    inner join  Your_Table_Name  Y on C.WeekC =Y.Week
    and  C.CustomerC =Y.Customer  and  C.productC =Y.product
```

Note :Please replace "Your_Table_Name" with exact table name and Try.

Comment: What is the purpose of "(WeekC ,CustomerC,  ProductC)" on the first line? The query seems to return the same results with or without it. Does that just clarify the columns you are pulling from the AS subquery?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this, using generic SQL, is to use a "derived table" like this:

```
select x.*
from tablex x
inner join (
    select Week, Customer, Product 
    from tablex 
    group by Week, Customer, Product
    having count(*) > 1
    ) d on x.Week = d.Week and x.Customer = d.Customer and x.Product = d.Product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `DISTINCT` like

```
select DISTINCT Customer,Product,Customer_Type,Price from Your_Table_Name
```

will look for DISTINCT combination.
Note: This query if of SQL Server

Comment: You are not considering Week. This query will return non-duplicate rows too which shouldn't be returned.

Comment: Please look at expected result it can have diff. week.

Answer (score 0):

From the expected result that you have pasted, it looks like you are not concerned about the week.
If you have a ID (incremental PK), it would be much simpler like below

select * from table where ID not in 
(select max(ID) from table group by Customer, Product, CustomerType having count(*) > 1 )

This is tested on MySQL. Do you have a ID column?
In case you don't have a ID column, try the below:

select max(week) week, Customer, Product, CustomerType, max(price) from device group by Customer, Product, CustomerType;

I have not verified this one.

Answer (score 0):

This will return your expected result set:

```
select *
from table
-- Teradata syntax to filter the result of an OLAP-function
-- (similar to HAVING after GROUP BY)
qualify
   count(*)
   over (partition by Week, Customer, product) > 1
```

For other DBMSes you will need to nest your query:

```
select *
from
 (
    select ..., 
       count(*)
       over (partition by Week, Customer, product) as cnt
    from table
 ) as dt
where cnt > 1
```

Edit:

After re-reading your description above Select might be not exactly what you want, because it will also return rows with a single type. Then switch to:

```
select *
from table
-- Teradata syntax to filter the result of an OLAP-function
-- (similar to HAVING after GROUP BY)
qualify -- at least two different types:
   min(Customer_Type) over (partition by Week, Customer, product)
<> max(Customer_Type) over (partition by Week, Customer, product)
```